# how to update content type for a sharepoint list item using REST api in O365?

Tags: office-365, rest, content-type

I want to update the content type of a list item. When I try to send content type name or content type id as a normal Field, it throws the following exception.

> A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected

Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What are you trying? Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: Actually, I'm using my own form which has a Combobox, that passes the contentType ID. With that value, I wanted to update the list item. So in request stream of HTTPwebRequest I'm passing 

`{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.Jul4ListItem'},'Title':'test','try':'fddata', 'pplId':11,'ContentType':'0x01000D2F316B81461947BCF69E20750971AA'}}`

which has the Content Type ID. But without contentType id, it updates perfectly but with the base content type 'Item'.

Comment: Have you tried this? `"ContentTypeId": "0x01000D2F316B81461947BCF69E207509‌​71AA"`

Comment: That's Wow. ya I'm passing ContentTypeId only right. It worked. Timely helped. Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ContentTypeId` instead of `ContentType`:

```
{
    '__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.Jul4ListItem'},
    'Title':'test'‌​,
    'try':'fddata', 
    'pplId':11, 
    'ContentTypeId':'0x01000D2F316B81461947BCF69E207509‌​71AA'
}
```